# Can we set themes in GTK 3 for Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, gtk3, gtk#

In Ubuntu, installing themes are as easy as copy-pasting GTK theme into the themes folder, then with the tweaks tool we can select the theme.

I couldn't find a working solution or workaround to apply themes.

Steps I have tried:

1. Installing the runtime
   The GTK runtime I am using is
   https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer/releases.
2. Get a theme from https://www.pling.com/p/1246387/
3. Extract the content to C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Gtk\3.24.24\share\themes
4. Edit settings.ini on C:\Users\Seiko Santana\AppData\Local\Gtk\3.24.24\etc\gtk-3.0\settings.ini putting `gtk-theme-name=Ultimate-Dark-(Cpt)-Violet`
5. Run any GtkSharp application.

It is still loading Adwaita theme. Did I miss something? I'm developing on .NET 6 and GtkSharp if that matters.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I put the theme file under the themes directory like so:

[image]

, and added the following code right after `Init` (if I put it before that, it causes a null exception).

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Init();
        Gtk.Settings.Default.ThemeName = "Ultimate-Dark-(Flat)-Violet";
```

and it worked:

[image]

Without that line, the default theme is like this, so it definitely worked.

[image]